# how to create a tray in QT like system tray

Tags: qt4, system, system-tray, windows, advanced-search

I created a qt application. In which there are several links to connect to other applications like MS Word, Excel,IE etc. When the corresponding button is clicked, it will link to that application. What I want to do that, whenever the particular application is minimized, it should go to the system tray of QT application ,not in the system tray.
So I have to create a system tray of QT.
All your suggestions are appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: to display something like the osx dock, there are already tools available like http://rocketdock.com/

Answer (score 2):

To create a system tray icon for a QT application the most convenient way is to use `QSystemTrayIcon` ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html ), but I am not sure how you can force Excel or Word to not minimize to the default tray but instead to go to your applications system tray icon's context menu.